How much is one to try to get fatha.kasra mistakes corrected in the Quranic verses written in Youtube videos?
Assalam-o-alaikum warahmatuAllahi wabarakatohu!
I was following a Surah Yaseen recitation on Youtube. The recitations of this qari really touch one's heart and are very beautiful. There were Arabic and English captions embedded in the video. However, the other day when I was following, I noticed mistakes in the vowel markings (fatha, kasra) in the Arabic captions. For example, in the following image, it should be fabasshirho (and not fabassharho) - this is one example, there are many mistakes of that sort.

So I left a respectful comment, requesting that them or their team looks into it. But I didn't receive a reply or notice any change in the video. I think they missed my comment.
My question is that how critical is it that I get it notified to them? Should I email or message (like direct message) to them on other social platforms or should I let it be? It is Quran, so I feel I should try to get this corrected, since I have seen it, so it has become my responsibility, and what if Allah questions me about it? I don't want Allah SWT to be disappointed (Allah forbid) in me.

Writing the kasra directly under the shadda instead of under the consonant is just a variation in Arabic script, not an actual error. If it was above the shadda, it would be an error.
Of note, the original manuscripts of the Qur'an were written before the Arabic vowels were even invented. While kasra-under-consonant may be more common in currently-printed Qur'ans, Islamically speaking neither method of writing it is more or less valid.
